# What happens when an electromagnetic wave encounters a resistor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

So I know that the electromagnetic wave travels down the transmission line between the conductors and the fields are related by the characteristic impedance of the transmission line, and I know that if you match the load resistor resistance to the characteristic impedance of the line, then there's no reflection.

But there must be a reflection right? but on a small lumped element time frame that is ignored in the lumped element model. Still -- I want to know what actually happens on that microscopic time scale when the electromagnetic wave reaches the resistor in a physics model rather than the lumped element model. I assumed at the immediate interface between the transmission line and the resistor, there would be a reflection, but I'm not sure how to calculate the characteristic impedance of the resistor medium. I'm assuming another reflection occurs when the boundary with the air is met, and this all bounces around, and the attenuation in the resistor just correct such that all these reflections appear at once and cancel out such that it appears like there's no reflection in the lumped element model..?

Comment: To talk about the microscopic scale you would need to provide more details. The whole point in lumped model is that all the details, e.g. how gradually the resistance in the resistor changes as one goes from wire to resistor, are lumped together. Once you will specify enough details you will find an answer, the answer will be very specific to your problem. I would suggest it may be better to get a solver of Maxwell's equations, do a CAD drawing of your setup, solve equations numerically, and see what happens.

Comment: Reacting to your "resistor medium". It looks like it may be more relevant to look how electromagnetic waves are affected by propagating through interfaces between media. Keep refractive index complex, and you will be able to model lossy media. [Fresnel Equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) is a good place to start.